# Scrollview returns back to top

Tags: android, xml

I have issue when my scrollview would return to the top I find this only happens when  the scroll reaches the start of richeditor. However, i find the scroll is working fine with edittext.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    android:ellipsize="end">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        >


        <EditText
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:id="@+id/descField1"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_desc"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/titleField"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


        <jp.wasabeef.richeditor.RichEditor
            android:id="@+id/descField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_desc"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
         />



    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Scrollview to

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

and remove these lines from EditText

```
android:layout_below="@+id/titleField"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

and remove this line from RichEditor

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```

Comment: Yeah sure post the link

Comment: https://github.com/rasselll/MessagingApp-master-master1 

Wanna look at the post_layout and activity_post

Comment: try it out yourself.